Wrapping long list in single line of code block in Jupyter Notebook VS Code
If I have a very long list that I input in a code block in Jupyter notebook on VS Code , how do I wrap it in a single line? I want to generate some plots based on data in the list, but do not want the code block to take up a large amount of space to display the entire content of the list, but instead want to wrap it in a single line.

What have you tried till now? What is the issue you faced? In python you can use this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html
